# How to get iSCSI multipath work on Windows 10 , should I do any adjustment in linux server side?

Tags: windows-10, iscsi, multipath

I have 8x18TB Raid10 mdadm volume on Ubuntu server. When I connect from Windows iSCSI speeds 220MB/sec read 375MB/sec write. I guess it is a iSCSI protocol bottleneck could not improve it. It leaves me multipath.

I have 2 nics on both server and client. I tried many things but could not figure out how to use Multipath or multiple sessions (in windows interface). Tried to connect sessions as

```
192.168.122.100 --> 192.168.122.110
192.168.123.100 --> 192.168.123.110
```

I see both portals in portals and create favorite as MPIO but when I use MCS it says it is already connected. Also tried to

```
192.168.122.100 --> 192.168.122.110
               |--> 192.168.122.111
```

Could not get it work. What adjustment should I do server side. I am clueless at the moment. By the way windows is windows10 PRO 20H2 so no restrictions on it I guess.

note: We try to make it work fluently with avid media composer. Since it asks for disks. If I cannot get the performance I need from ISCSI, I plan to switch to nbd ? Any good alternatives to iSCSI or other suggestions which works over 10Gbe ethernets and switch  ?

Edit: I stumbled upon CNA cards RDMA ISER solution gonna try it ...
Suggestions are still welcome.

Comment: Please update the last part of your question, it's not good formatted and asked. Since you get over 200mb/s I believe that the server is already using 10gbit?

Comment: From what I've found it could be a bug of Windows 10. 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9796
It should work and according to forums it will until your reboot the PC. You will need to enable it again after reboot. 
Might be helpful as well: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1b5ec2f8-8ba8-4320-8cac-89fc623f83b9/windows-10-mpio?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: I have edited the question and I am using X520T2 Intel cards both on server and client.